# Hide progress bar once images are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I have a progress bar with Bootstrap, CSS and jQuery. Everything works fine but I would like this bar disappears when all images are loaded.
For this I tried to put in the following script a:

```
if(n==100) { $('#fabbar').hide(); }
```

Here's the script :

```
$(function () {
    var n = 0,
    $imgs = $('img.gallery'),
    val = 100 / $imgs.length,
    $bar = $('#fabbar');

    $imgs.load(function () {
      n = n + val;
      // for displaying purposes
      $bar.width(n + '%').text(n + '%');            
    });

  if(n==100) { $('#fabbar').hide(); }

  });
```

and into my body, I have :

```
    <div class="progress progress-info progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar" id='fabbar' style="width: 20%">0%</div>
    </div>
    
    <a href="images/1.jpg"><img class="gallery" src="images/1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/2.jpg"><img class="gallery" src="images/2.jpg" ></a>    
    <a href="images/3.jpg"><img class="gallery" src="images/3.jpg" ></a>
    <a href="images/4.jpg"><img class="gallery" src="images/4.jpg" ></a>

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use WaitforImages jquery plugin for that:
https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Here is how it should work:

```
$(function () {
    var n = 0,
        $imgs = $('img'),
        val = 100 / $imgs.length,
        $bar = $('#fabbar');

    $imgs.load(function () {
        n = n + val;
        // for displaying purposes
        $bar.width(n + '%').text(n + '%');
    });

});

$('body').waitForImages(function() {
    // All descendant images have loaded, now hide the progress bar.
    $(".bar_wrap").fadeOut();
});
```

Check out the demo((click the run button))
http://jsfiddle.net/yphM4/24/

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
$(function () {
    var n = 0,
        $imgs = $('img.gallery'),
        val = 100 / $imgs.length,
        $bar = $('#fabbar');
    $("img").one('load', function () {
        n = n + val;
        // for displaying purposes
        $bar.width(n + '%').text(n + '%');
         n === 100?$('#fabbar').hide():false;       
    }).each(function () {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
});
```

Comment: with this, the progress bar doesn't progress. I can almost make it disappear with : $(function () {
    var n = 0,
        $imgs = $('img.gallery'),
        val = 100 / $imgs.length,
        $bar = $('#fabbar');
    $("img").one('load', function () {
        n = n + val;
        // for displaying purposes
        $bar.width(n + '%').text(n + '%');
         n === 100?$('#fabbar').hide():false;       
    });

}); but a blanck bar remains after 100% loading, how can this be explained ?